# Galaxy S7 Nougat Full Icons

Tags: android, galaxy, android-7.0-nougat

I wanted to ask how to change the app icon of my app on a Galaxy S7 running on Android Nougat (see attached screenshot) to fill the whole icon space.
Is there a way to do this?

EDIT: I think it's because these apps have square icons and mine is circular. Is there a way to make it square for Galaxy S7 Nougat devices and for all others round?

[image: My app's icon and the icon of another App from Google Play]

Comment: check with a single icon inside drawble folder with size 192*192.

Comment: And if I'm using Android Studio with mipmap instead of drawable?

Comment: I think it's because these apps have square icons and mine is circular. Is there a way to make it square for Galaxy S7 Nougat devices and for all others round?

Comment: Share also your launcher icons.

Comment: It's because these apps have square icons and mine is circular. Is there a way to make it square for Galaxy S7 Nougat devices and for all others round?

Comment: yes man .. its the shape that is causing pblm. icon i was using is square shaped

Comment: How did you solved that problem?

Comment: I didn't solve this yet. Seems like the only way is to shape the icon like this. It's also possible to change just the xxxhdpi, because the Galaxy S7 uses this size for the launcher. But other devices will also get this shape, But for them it doesn't look good :/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can disable this by adding a meta-data element to your manifest:

```
<application>
    <meta-data android:name="com.samsung.android.icon_container.has_icon_container" android:value="true"/>
</application>
```

Comment: Wow, impeccable timing. I was just looking in to this now. This works great! Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

This solution is only for user's end:

Go to settings -> display -> icon frames -> icon only.
This should change the icons into full size icons.

Comment: Yes, but only for me and not all of my users ^^

Comment: We are talking about a published app and no private one ;)

Comment: This is great. I was cringing at the icon frames. To me, it makes more sense to default this to off.

Answer (score 4):

From https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.1.html

> Apps can now define circular launcher icons, which are used on devices that support them. When a launcher requests an app icon, the framework returns either android:icon or android:roundIcon, depending on the device build configuration. Because of this, apps should make sure to define both `android:icon` and `android:roundIcon` resources when responding to launcher intents. You can use Image Asset Studio to design round icons.

While that may not be sufficient to deal with Samsung's "special" white frame for icons, this gif shows a few ideas for creating icons that look good whether they are the normal size or framed "Squircle" style.

https://www.androidcentral.com/sites/androidcentral.com/files/article_images/2016/12/squircles.gif[image: Different icons]

In any event this means you now have to worry about a normal icon, a round icon and a Samsung-ized icon and there is no way to provide an icon for the Samsung-specific launcher design.

Answer (score 4):

I met the same problem and tried various things. Now I found one interesting thing.

If you make an icon without any transparency, the icon will be the full size on the Nougat android phone. When I made an icon in the paint.exe and saved it as .png, there was no problem.

I think this will help you.

EDIT : below is what I met, explained in my comment

[image]

EDIT2 : the sizes and shapes of two icons (with and without transparency) are identical. the only difference is one has transparency and the other has white background. Definitely I don't mean that I deleted transparency and enlarged the image.

EDIT3 : more explanation about my icons @Hadas

[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post. Also check this [what can I do instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: Oh, now I see mine is not the exact answer of the EDITED question but somewhat related to the ORIGINAL question. What I met is 1) I used square icon for my app and it looked good in Marshmallow 2) When I upgraded my android phone to Nougat, the icon was changed smaller so that the icon was not full size 3) Checking my other app icons, I found some are full size and some are NOT. It was not the problem of square or round. All were square. 4) With changing the icon png file in drawable-xxxhdpi to have no transparency, the icon changed to be FULL. 5) I thought it's weird and worth to announce.

Comment: With several hours of deep consideration, I found one possibility. Even it looks like rectangular to human, it can look like circle to machine. Does android distinguish rectangular and circle with the amount of transparency or existence of transparency at some specific points? All my app icons are rectangular to me but some of them have round edges. Because the amounts of rounding are different among icons, sometimes android Nougat think some are round icons rather than rectangular icons so it makes them smaller and make problems. Am I talking something plausible? I'm not sure.

Comment: So if I still want my icon to have rounded edges on Android 6.0 can I still have some transparency? can you give an example of an icon with rounded edges on 6.0 that still looks good on 7.0? @Yong-SunChoi

Comment: @Hadas My original icon had rectangular border with rounded edges. Outside of edge borders, there was transparency(4 small parts). And also there were several small transparent areas inside of border (background but the border was perfectly continuous). 1) I removed all the transparent parts in the icon and it worked. 2) I removed only inside transparent parts and it worked well too. So, still, I'm not sure what is the critical condition for the android decision. But anyway you can make good rounded edge icon for 6.0 and full size icon for 7.0 with one icon.

Comment: @Hadas I inserted my icon images in the original answer with EDIT3. The border is white so it cannot be seen easily.

Comment: Great answer, helped me a lot. And this is indeed interesting, I can't find any formal explanation about this. Thanks for the addition of the icons to your answer!